# pycharm is warning me that it cant read an abstractpropery

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I have the following Python 2 script, which runs as expected, but gives two warnings in the PyCharm IDE. May I ignore them?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# coding=UTF-8
import random,logging
from abc import ABCMeta,abstractproperty

class Upper(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        self._prop = "abc"

    @abstractproperty
    def prop(self):
        pass

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, prop):
        pass

    def peng(self):
        print self.prop # <-- Warning 1
        self.prop = "xyz"

class Lower(Upper):
    @property
    def prop(self):
        return self._prop

    @prop.setter 
    def prop(self, prop): # <-- Warning 2
        self._prop = prop


if __name__ == '__main__':
    upperObj = Lower()
    print upperObj.prop
    upperObj.prop = "def"
    print upperObj.prop
    upperObj.peng()
    print upperObj.prop
```

The output is as expected:

```
abc
def
def
xyz
```

Pycharm gives me two warnings:

1. "Property prop can't be read"
2. "Signature of method Lower.prop() does not match signature of base method in class Upper"

I think both warnings are false positives because in the first case, the property is defined and implemented (although in different classes) and in the second case I don't see how the method signatures diverge. Are these warnings false positives and may be ignored?

Comment: I filled an issue about these warnings https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20322

Comment: The issue should be fixed in the EAP which was released on March 1, 2017. It is available here: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that PyCharm simply does not know about the @abstractproperty annotation. So this warning can be ignored.